# AJAX/JQuery response time performance widget

Tags: jquery, ajax, widget, response-time

I'm looking for an AJAXian widget that shows the time between client browser and server. Any ideas?

Comment: I need it to appear inline in the page - so FireFox plugins like YSlow won't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug for firefox show this.

Comment: I need it to appear inline in the page - so FireFox plugins like YSlow won't do the trick. – Ralph 0 secs ago