# how to get length of jQuery .load AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way I can get the length of an Ajax request done via jQuery's `.load();`?

As in the amount of time it takes to send the request and load the elements from the corresponding page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498503/find-out-how-long-an-ajax-request-took-to-complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just before the start of the `.load`, store the current time: `startTime = new Date();`. In the callback, get the current time again, and subtract the start time. You'll get the elapsed time in milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that there would be a way inside the function, but this works.