# Javascript : Pinging server or getting processing time?

Tags: javascript, ping, icmp

I am trying to make a simple ping test between the client and the web server.
Right now, I am only sending get request and waiting for an answer but this is not accurate at all.
I know there is no way with JS to send an ICMP ping.

But is there a way to know how much time the server took to process the request ?
If I can get that I could have a pretty good estimate of a ping.

I want to get the time it took to process the request on the server and that does not include the time for the packets to travel. Because the travel time is what I want.

Should I use another language ?

rXp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find out how long an Ajax request took to complete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498503/find-out-how-long-an-ajax-request-took-to-complete)

Comment: I would like to know the process time on the server without the time it took for the packets to travel.

Comment: Is the server yours or someone else's? The only way for this feature to work is to have the server give you the processing information. If the server is yours to control, you can alter your code and add profiling information. If it isn't, you can't get processing info - only an estimate.

Comment: I have an FTP access. I could use PHP but that's it.