# How can I reset my Ajax request on every click to improve the performance?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

index.php:

```
    <div class="start">START</div>
    <div class="content"></div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
```

update1.php:

```
     <div class="fire">FIRE<div>
     <div class="result"></div>
```

update2.php:

```
$json = array(
        'unique' => uniqid(),
    );
echo json_encode($json);
```

script.js:

```
$(document).off("click", ".start").on("click", ".start", function (event) {

             $.ajax({
                url: "update1.php",
                data: {},
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    $(".content").html(data);
                }
            })
});


$(document).off("click", ".fire").on("click", ".fire", function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "update2.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            encode: true,
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                $(".result").html(data.unique);
            }
        });
    });
```

I load some data via Ajax and after that I load a Unique ID with json encode. It is working well. The only problem is, that on every click "FIRE" the loading of the Unique ID is getting slower and slower.

The loading time is more or less like this

- Click "FIRE" ---> Loading time of Unique ID: 0sek
- Click "FIRE" ---> Loading time of Unique ID: 2sek
- Click "FIRE" ---> Loading time of Unique ID: 4sek
- Click "FIRE" ---> Loading time of Unique ID: really long that the mouse waiting symbol is turning and turning.

Note: The Unique ID is just an example. Same thing is happening with a normal variable

---

I tested `update2.php` with `$time_start = microtime(true);`, `$time_end = microtime(true);` and `$execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start)/60;`

The result is:

- Click "FIRE" ---> 4.91499900818E-5
- Click "FIRE" ---> 5.54800033569E-5
- Click "FIRE" ---> 5.33978144328E-5
- Click "FIRE" ---> 5.43832778931E-5

Comment: are you sure, it's the ajax response time? could you measure the runtime of update2.php with something like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245971/accurate-way-to-measure-execution-times-of-php-scripts

Comment: @errand Yes, I will check this

Comment: I checked your code in my local server and call ajax every time it take 1ms fine.

Comment: your code is working fine on my machine

Comment: maybe the code is just a snippet of a bigger set of functions. check out this discussions and aristoteles and grayedFox 's answers - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498503/find-out-how-long-an-ajax-request-took-to-complete - due to the javascript event handling queue, the response might be there faster, but js is still busy doing something else...

Comment: @errand I tested the loading time on my php file. I will post the result in my question

Comment: @errand What do you think of the result?

Comment: @errand Ok, so you think it could help if I put something like `return false;` at the end of my ajax function?

Comment: so at least, you can be sure, that it is not server runtime. checked already the second linked thread, to find out if it's kind of a runtime delay due to event queue backlog?

Comment: @errand I could find something out! I removed all my other functions in my script.js. And  now it is fast. So some functions are running, although I think I didn't told them to

Comment: it's been a pleasure to help - i guess you know now, how to proceed (tons of console.log messages) to find the loophole ;)

Comment: @errand Yes thanks to your advice I tested it. Do you like to put your advice as an answer? So I can mark it as answered. How can I do that with the console.log message?

Comment: console log explanation would be to much for this comment section - but you find enough information about that via google. every browser has a console window, which you open by pressing f12 - so if you put a lot of console log messages into your javascript, you can then read the log in your browser... since your question turned out to be more trouble shoot and no actual solvable question - my links to other topics are not really an answer.

Comment: @errand Ok, thanks a lot for your advices. A very good help!